# Is it fine, by design, to use istream operator in constructor

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The following is a C++ code for the constructor of `linear_program` class I have created. The problem is that I have a feeling that, by design, I should overload the `>>` operator for this class instead of just using `>>` it in constructor for the class. But then I have to allocate memory dynamically which depends on input taken so I canno segregate the logic completely and even if I overload the operator then I will not be able to take all input at once. That is why I do not see a benefit in overloading `>>` in this case.

```
linear_program::linear_program() {
    cin >> dim >> no_constr;  
    lp = new plane[no_constr];
    double *temp = new double [dim];
    double constant;
    for (int i = 0; i < no_constr; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dim;++j) {
                    cin >> temp[j];
            }
            cin >> constant;
            lp[i].set_plane(temp, constant, dim);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < no_constr; ++i) {
            cin >> cost[i];
    }
}
```

Is this acceptable by design standards. I would also like to know if there are other healthy alternatives for such cases.

Comment: This might be acceptable for toy programs or demos, but not in reusable production code. The reason is that this forces a certain text format on the user and disallows input via other means. The way that I see it, the linear_program should be a datatype and not enforce any storage specifics. As such, I'd only add an output operator for debugging, but no serialization. BTW: Another no-no is the use of array new, that's what std::vector is for, unless you have advanced requirements. For a beginner, stay with vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by 'fine'. But I would suggest to keep object initializations in a constructor, and move the business logic(that does not correspond to creation of that object) to another function.

A constructor should initialize the object, nothing more.

```
linear_program::linear_program(int dim, int no_constr):
 m_noConstr(no_constr), m_Dim(dim)
  {
    lp = new plane[no_constr];
    double constant;
  }

void linear_program::get_something()
{
   double *temp = new double [m_Dim];
   for (int i = 0; i < m_noConstr; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m_Dim;++j) {
                    cin >> temp[j];
            }
            cin >> constant;
            lp[i].set_plane(temp, constant, dim);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < no_constr; ++i) {
            cin >> cost[i];
    }
}

//Call get_something() after the object has been initialized. It makes reading the code easier.
```

Comment: can you suggest something in this case. I mean anything better